# Add Custom Caption Button

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, docking, syncfusion

I am using [Sync fusion docking manager](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/docking-manager) and I want to add custom caption button to my floating window.

I found [solution for Win Forms](http://help.syncfusion.com/ug/windows%20forms/index.html#!Documents/customcaptionbuttons.htm), but can't add it to [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) project.
Please help.

Answer (score -1):

This response was already posted in the Syncfusion support forums.

We can add buttons in the header of child window using HeaderTemplate property. We have prepared a sample and tried to meet your requirement. In the sample, we have created a data template with button and set it as header template of child window using HeaderTemplate attached property. 
[Sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/forum/120046/ze/Docking_HeaderTemplate-1238073649)

Comment: If you need a better solution, please post a comment and I will ask the developers to work on the solution.